where to find Crystal report - Merge Modules for Visual Studio 2022
I am developing a VB.Net win application in Visual Studio 2022 and I have installed Crystal Report 64 bit runtime software, Crystal Report for visual studio 2022 in my machine. I don't want to install Crystal Reports to every client machine when installing my application. So what I did is, when setup file is creating through setup project in visual studio 2022 I am planning to include the "CrystalReports11_NET_Embeddedreporting.msm" file as merge module. So that there is no need to install crystal report in the client machine where I am installing the application.
But the problem is, I am not able to find the file "CrystalReports11_NET_Embeddedreporting.msm" in the below shown location in my laptop. Actually, after common files, there is no "Merge Modules" folder.
 c:\program files (x86)\common files\merge modules\crystal11_net_embeddedreporting.msm

From where I can find Merge modules for visual studio 2022
Or do I need to purchase the original crystal reports ???
My OS is Win 10 64 bit.
